# Copy *.so from .jar (via Maven) to apk

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, java-native-interface, .so

I imported a library via Maven on my Android project. This library has three .so. When I generate an APK, I would copy *.so on my APK.

Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: I assume you use Android Studio. Look for these **.so** files under **app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar**. You can simply add this directory to the list of your **jniLib** srcDirs.

Comment: In fact, I have this bug since I updated the gradle classpath version from 1.3.0 to 1.5.0. I don't know if is a bug, but since I come back on the older version (1.3.0), shared library is automatically copied in my APK

Answer (score 0):

Put the `.so` files inside `jniLibs/armeabi/` folder and they will be automatically bundled with the apk.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I can't do that, I obtain an error when I drag and drop .so file from .jar "Refactoring connot be performed. File **/**/*.so is located in a JAR file"

Answer (score 0):

First you need to extract the .so files from the jar. This can be done in various ways depending on your OS. In linux you may find an option to extract archive on  right click menu. In windows and MAC also similar options will be available. After extracting .so files from jar, you need to copy these .so files to sub folders in jniLibs folder ( It should be created at /app/src/main/ if your module is default one. ie, app) Also note that .so files should be copied to relevant sub folders inside jniLibs. ie, armeabi .so files should be in armeabi and x86 .so files if there are any should be put in x86 folder.

Comment: Thank you, If I understand, I must do that manually. In fact, each day, I synchronize my project with gradle  for the latest version of the library. So each day, I must extract .so file?